# Find if added in domain class - not using findBy

Tags: grails, grails-domain-class

I have domain classes => many-to-many and associate them using addTo.

```
class Books {
    static belongsTo = Author
}

class Author {
    static belongsTo = Book
    static hasMany = [books: Book]
}
```

Controller:

```
author.addToBooks(mybook).save()
```

=> I want to check if mybook is already added to author. Is the a way to check if the book is already added to author (hopefully not using findBy)? Something like

```
if (author.isAdded(mybook))
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default defining as `hasMany` will use a `java.util.Set`. Since a Set is a collection that contains no duplicates, this means you can call `author.addToBooks()` with the same Book and it will not be added more than once - so it isn't necessary to check if a book is present.

However, to check for a Book in the Set, you can use `author.books.contains(book)`